# JSON display response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a script which grabs another JavaScript which is made using PHP, it all works fine, but im trying to build in some error handling incase there is an issue. At the moment the error works if it cannot find the file, but I would like it to display a message from the PHP code if there is an error. I thought using JSON would work, but im very new to it, and admit to not knowing what im doing.

If someone could help me get this working, as at the moment I am not getting the message response message appear in the alert.

I have the following JQuery code:

```
graphURL = 'functions/ICP_summary_graph.php';
graphData = '?ICP=' + ICPSet;
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: 'get',
    URL: graphURL,
    data: graphData,
    success: function (data) {
            var reponse = jQuery.parseJSON(data.response); 
            alert("response :  "+reponse);
            //$('#expconchart').html(data.response);
    },
    error: function(data) {
            $('#meterloader').hide();
            $('#meterbox').html("<div><p class='textcentre bold red'>There was an error loading the chart.</p>");
    } 
});
$.getScript(graphURL + graphData);
```

and this PHP:

```
//GENERATE GRAPH
//SET RESULT ARRAY
$result = array();
//CONNECT TO DATABASE
if(!require('../../connect.php')){
    $result['response'] = "Unable to aquire connection";
    header("content-type: application/json");
    exit(json_encode($result));
} else {
...
```

Any help greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Any specific question ?

Comment: `getScript()` is the wrong method; you want `ajax()` or `get()` or `getJSON()`.

Comment: You may use `if(file_exists('file.php')){ // require }`

Comment: @SheikhHeera I am aware of that. I did actually just put that in as an example, but have instances where queries are performed and need to tell the user if there is a problem and the graph wont display.